# Unique weak solution of the Robin Problem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How would you prove that $u = 0$ is the only weak solution to the Robin problem :

$$ \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        -\Delta u = 0 & \mbox{in } \Omega \\
        \partial_{\nu} u + u = 0 & \mbox{on } \partial \Omega
    \end{array}
\right. $$
(under smooth assumptions we know that the weak formulation of the Robin problem is well-posed.)

Comment: $u\Delta u =0$ in $\Omega$, so $\int_{\Omega}u\Delta u\,dV=0$. Now, integrate by parts, and analyze the resulting signs carefully. (if $u$ is complex valued then start with $\overline{u}\Delta u =0$)